# Is it possible to install crystal reports as a feature using WIX

Tags: installation, wix, wix3.5

So I know how to take the bootstrap for crystal reports and use it as a pre-req so that crystal reports gets installed if it does not exist.  But is there a way to make it optional through a feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Crystal Reports website](http://resources.businessobjects.com/support/additional_downloads/runtime.asp) using either an MSI installer (using a bootstrapper) or using merge modules.  You want to [include the merge module](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/merging_msm_into_msi.htm) in your project and then selectively install that module using features.